# Need to default payment form to "card on file" using Stripe(more) gravity forms plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, stripe-payments, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm using the [(more)Stripe](https://gravityplus.pro/gravity-forms-stripe/) for gravity forms plugin to store credit card details on my users initial purchase so I can offer them a 1 click upsell on the confirmation page without having to re=enter credit card details.

The credit card details are being stored correctly but the stored card is not selected by default on the upsell page.

The plugin author told me to control the default card in the javascript but hasn't provided any further details.

I'm hiding the credit card form on the upsell page so users only have to click my call to action button as shown [here](https://training.handcraftedbusinessfilms.com/blueprint-webinar-3-killer-strategies/bfb-stabilization-up-one-time-offer/)

You can see the form un-hidden without default card selected [here](http://screencast.com/t/yPLTrFZjHsg)

Here is the credit card field js:

```
    /**
 *
 */
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( jQuery ) {
    jQuery( "input[name='gform_payment_method']" ).on( 'click', gfpStripeToggleCreditCard );
} );

function gfpStripeToggleCreditCard() {

    var card = jQuery( this );

    if ( jQuery( "#gform_payment_method_creditcard" ).is( ":checked" ) ) {
        gfpStripeShowCreditCardFields();
    }
    else {
        gfpStripeHideCreditCardFields();
        gfpStripeSetCardNumber( card );
    }
}

function gfpStripeShowCreditCardFields() {
    var card_number = jQuery( '.gform_card_icon_container' ).next();
    var card_number_label = card_number.next();
    var card_exp_and_code = jQuery( '.ginput_cardextras' );
    var card_name = card_exp_and_code.next();

    card_number.fadeIn();
    card_number_label.fadeIn();
    card_exp_and_code.fadeIn();
    card_name.fadeIn();
}

function gfpStripeHideCreditCardFields() {
    var card_number = jQuery( '.gform_card_icon_container' ).next();
    var card_number_label = card_number.next();
    var card_exp_and_code = jQuery( '.ginput_cardextras' );
    var card_name = card_exp_and_code.next();

    card_number.fadeOut();
    card_number_label.fadeOut();
    card_exp_and_code.fadeOut();
    card_name.fadeOut();
}

function gfpStripeSetCardNumber( card ) {
    var form = card.closest( 'form' );
    var field_id = card.closest( 'li' ).attr( 'id' );
    field_id = field_id.split( '_' );
    field_id = field_id[2];
    var card_number = card.val();
    form.append( "<input type='hidden' name='input_" + field_id + ".1' value='" + card_number + "' />" );
    var card_type = jQuery( 'div.gform_payment_' + card_number ).text();
    card_type = card_type.trim();
    card_type = card_type.split( '(' );
    card_type = card_type[0].trim();
    form.append( "<input type='hidden' name='input_" + field_id + ".4' value='" + card_type + "' />" );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the default option with a `click()`, by adding it after the bind:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( jQuery ) {
     //binds to the plugin's function
    jQuery( "input[name='gform_payment_method']" ).on( 'click', gfpStripeToggleCreditCard );
     //triggers the change to default option
    jQuery( "input#ID_OF_DEFAULT_OPTION" ).click();
} );
```

You just need to inspect the radio button input you want to be selected by default (in your browser: right-click+inspect), look into the id attribute of that input, copy it and replace `ID_OF_DEFAULT_OPTION` by what you find in there.

This new line can be invoked instead in another `.ready` block after the plugin's js file is referenced (in the page itself), this way you're not altering anything in the plugin...

You can also use another selector if the id is a random one:

```
    jQuery( "input[id^=gform_payment_method_card_]" ).click();
```

This means you're selecting the input button that has an id attribute starting with `gform_payment_method_card_`.

Comment: Thanks, the ID of the radio button appears to be unique though, you can see the screenshot [link]http://screencast.com/t/6VaE306P8BXN

Comment: @jamesscaggs I edited the answer just now explaining that you can use alternate selectors to get the right radio button. You can place any link in the comments in here by using `[link's name](http://link.url)`. Here's [your screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/6VaE306P8BXN).

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">jQuery( document ).ready( function ( jQuery ) {
     //binds to the plugin's function
    jQuery( "input[name='gform_payment_method']" ).on( 'click', gfpStripeToggleCreditCard );
     //triggers the change to default option
    jQuery( "input[id^=gform_payment_method_card_]" ).click();
} );</script>` 

I've got this inserted just below the /head tag on the page but Still not getting default to my stored card. What's missing?

Comment: That finally worked when we moved the script to just before closing body tag. Thanks!

Comment: @jamesscaggs glad it worked! That script can actually be one line only: `<script type="text/javascript">jQuery( document ).ready( function ( jQuery ) { jQuery( "input[id^=gform_payment_method_card_]" ).click(); } );</script>` if it's placed after the code of that "credit card field js". You can also inspect and search to locate where the `gfpStripeToggleCreditCard` is called on the page (normally when you add inline JS you want to do it after the related plugins are invoked, i.e. after jQuery or others are loaded:).